# How can I remove any caret symbols in a string?

Tags: java, regex, string, caret

I'm using a regex string that contains a carat (^) symbol somewhere inside of it.  Is there a way in Java to remove these symbols?  Here are a few methods I've tried:

```
string = "some^string";

string = string.replaceAll("\\^", "");
string = string.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("\\^"), "");
string = string.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("\u2038"), "");
```

None of which have worked.  What am I missing?

Comment: `string = string.replaceAll("\\^", "");` works fine for me... I've copy-pasted to main method and worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need to use regular expressions at all:

```
string = string.replace("^", "");
```

However, the first of your examples works too:

```
public class Test {   
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String string = "some^string";
        string = string.replaceAll("\\^", "");
        System.out.println(string); // Prints somestring
    }
}
```

... so it's entirely possible that your problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

`string.replaceAll("\\^", "");` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Pls. delete last 2 lines from above your code and do write below things only then check.

string = "some^string";

string = string.replaceAll("\^", "");

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try using another variable name, like for example:

```
String str1 = string.replace("^", "1");
```

and use the new `str1`, instead of the old `string`.